# Launch ElasticSearch 6.4.3 with Spring Boot 2.0.3 - Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I tried almost everything, I see for each minor version change a complex matrix of dependencies must be respected and I think I am almost there. But Spring doesn't Boot with the error: `Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository'`
Which shouldn't be created at this point because I'm just trying to launch the app, not instantiating anything.

The pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>SpringBoot</name>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <elasticsearch.version>6.4.3</elasticsearch.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- ############## -->
        <!-- Elastic Search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, for Embedded Elasticsearch, comment this if connect to external 
        elastic search server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ####### -->
        <!-- Web MVC -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ####################################################### -->
        <!-- Hybernate and MySQL, You touch something, you broke it! -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My EsConfig.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.myapp;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;


@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.myapp.servicesboot.article.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.servicesboot.article"})
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.home:C:\\Program Files\\Java\\elasticsearch-6.4.3}")
    private String elasticsearchHome;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.cluster.name:eZqui83}")
    private String clusterName;

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        try {
            final Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder()
                    .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                    .put("path.home", elasticsearchHome)
                    .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
            TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

            return client;
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EsConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

Some Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.CreateIndexRequestBuilder.execute()Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ListenableActionFuture;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.myapp.ServicesBoot.main(ServicesBoot.java:22) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.CreateIndexRequestBuilder.execute()Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ListenableActionFuture;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:500) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:500) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:485) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
```

ArticleRepository.java

```
package com.myapp.servicesboot.article.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.myapp.servicesboot.article.model.Article;

@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Article, String> {

    Page<Article> findByAuthorsName(String name, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"authors.name\": \"?0\"}}]}}")
    Page<Article> findByAuthorsNameUsingCustomQuery(String name, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": {\"match_all\": {}}, \"filter\": {\"term\": {\"tags\": \"?0\" }}}}")
    Page<Article> findByFilteredTagQuery(String tag, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": {\"match\": {\"authors.name\": \"?0\"}}, \"filter\": {\"term\": {\"tags\": \"?1\" }}}}")
    Page<Article> findByAuthorsNameAndFilteredTagQuery(String name, String tag, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Is there any step by step, version by version guide to start this ElasticSearch with SpringBoot?

Can you help me to figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Data Lovelace release train supports Elasticsearch 6.4. It’s used by Spring Boot 2.1 by default.

Your simplest option is to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1 and use the versions provided by its dependency management.

Comment: Thanks Andy, the problem with upgrading spring boot to 2.1 is that it leads to many other issues such as `The server time zone value is unrecognized` wchich I couldn't solve with any workaround found on internet nor overriding jdbc behaviors, or `duplicated beans definition` (beans which I didn't declared), and others, so the 2.0.3 was until now the version that brought me the farest. I didn't found clear documentation or a working example, so I'm trying to patchwork all the solutions of developers that had all those struggles.

Comment: Sorry to hear you've had trouble upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1, but I still think that's the best solution. Spring Boot itself won't create duplicate beans so something in your application or one of your dependencies must be doing so. You can also enable bean definition overriding (the default behaviour in 2.0) by setting `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`. If this doesn't help, I'd recommend asking another question focussing on your problem with an upgrade to 2.1.

Comment: Yeah, I did that of course :) I agree with you anyway, this also is a dead end, so I should anyway push the efforts to the last version.